# UI Router - Validation on state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am implementing a multi step wizard view for accepting data from the user.
The routing is working correctly. Only thing I am struggling with is how to validate the data that is received in this state before the next step is shown.

What I have now is following configuration. The problem is `$stateChangeStart` event is triggered when we do `$state.go` (or other alternatives, like changing the hash of the url).
So, every time I do, `$state.go` it triggers the `$stateChangeStart` event and it seems to be stuck in an infinite loop.

Any advice?

```
    app.run(function($rootScope,$state,$http){
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            var validationUrl = fromState.validationUrl;

            if(validationUrl){ // we don't need validation for the very first step.
                event.preventDefault();
                var validationPromise = $http.post(validationUrl);

                validationPromise.then(function(){
                    $state.go(toState,toParams);
                });

                validationPromise.catch(function(){
                    console.log('errors');
                });
            }
        });
```

EDIT: Additional Data that may be needed.

This is my `StepsFactory`

```
define(function(){
    return {
        step1:{
            template:'templates/step1-tab.html',
            controller:'StepsController',
            validationUrl:'/validateStep1'
        },
        step2:{
            template:'templates/step2-tab.html',
            controller:'StepsController',
            validationUrl:'/valudateStep2'
        }
    };
});
```

Routes Configuration

```
    app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('application');

        $stateProvider
        .state('step1',{
            url:'/step1',
            templateUrl:StepsFactory.step1.template,
            controller: StepsFactory.step1.controller,
            validationUrl:StepsFactory.step1.validationUrl,
            stateConfig:StepsFactory.step1
        })
        .state('create',{
            url:'/create',
            abstract:true,
            templateUrl:'templates/create-substeps.html',
            controller:'AbstractStepsController'
        })
        .state('create.step2',{
            url:'/step2',
            //templateUrl:StepsFactory.step2.template
        });
    });
```

Please ignore syntax errors (if any), I've directly copy pasted from the source. But everything is working correctly apart from that issue where it makes the code get stuck in infinite loop.

Comment: How about using resolve for all the states that need validation?

Comment: That sounds interesting. However, if I were to follow that approach (using resolve) then I'd have to manually put resolve logic in each route. I want the mechanism that decide whether to go to next step or not at one place only. Can it be done with resolve? But this surely is a food for thought. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to solve it with some hack and I confess that I still don't understand how or why this works! All I know is this works.

Hacky way.

```
    app.run(function($rootScope,$state,$http){
        var shouldSkip;
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            if(shouldSkip) return;
            var validationUrl = fromState.validationUrl;

            if(validationUrl){ // we don't need validation for the very first step.
                event.preventDefault();
                var validationPromise = $http.post(validationUrl);

                validationPromise.then(function(){
                    shouldSkip=true;
                    $state.go(toState,toParams);
                });

                validationPromise.catch(function(){
                    shouldSkip=false;
                    console.log('errors');
                });
            }
        });
```